# Data Classification

Tags: permissions, site

We create the Data Classifcation Policy , howevre the site owner are able to change it from the Site information tab .[image]

WHen owner click on SIte setting and site information , they will be able to change the Classification. 
[image]

Is there any option to restrict not to change the data classification by site owner

Comment: Hi Kundan - did my answer help?  If it answered your question, please could you accept the answer?

Answer (score 2):

No.  The Site Owner can change (almost) anything on a Sharepoint Site.  If you don't want an individual to be a Site Owner, then change the Site Owner to someone else.

What you are experiencing is the normal behaviour.  It's best not to appoint someone who is too wild and untrustworthy by nature as a Site Owner, people with such a nature would be better suited to Sales or HR!

Here is a [Microsoft link on Sharepoint permissions](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc721640.aspx).